# $f(z)=\sum_{|n|>N}\left(\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac1n\right)$ converges uniformly on the disk $\{z\in\mathbb C\mid |z|<N\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

> Let $N$ be a fixed integer and $z\in\mathbb C$. Show that the the series $$f(z)=\sum_{|n|>N}\left(\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac1n\right)$$
>   Converges uniformly on the disk $\{z\in\mathbb C\mid |z|<N\}$.

By virtue of the symmetry, the last term cancels with its opposite, so we can rewrite it as $$f(z)=\sum_{n>N}\left(\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac1{z+n}\right)$$ My first attempt was to try and use the Weierstrass M-test to show that the limit is uniform.

We have $|z\pm n|\geq\left||z|-n\right|=n-|z|>n-N$, but then $\left|\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac1{z+n}\right|\leq \frac{2}{n-N}$. However, this is not enough to bound the series.

By Conrad's tip:

$$\left|\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac1n\right|=\left|\frac{z}{n(z-n)}\right|\leq \left|\frac{N}{n(|n|-N)}\right|=\left|\frac{N}{n((N+1)|n|-N(|n|+1))}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n((1+\frac{1}{N})|n|-|n|-1)}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n\left(\frac{|n|}N-1\right)}\right|$$

But that's as small as I can manage to create the error on the $-N$ term.

Comment: The whole point is actually not to cancel the free term but combine it with the $z$ term and note that the result is $\Sigma{O(\frac{N}{n^2})}$ which obviously converges absolutely and uniformly

Comment: @Conrad that's the first thing I tried but it is now apparent that I had momentarily forgotten how to add fractions properly

Comment: No problem - usually the reason a seemingly cancelling term is added is because of its improving convergence properties

Comment: @Conrad Upon further thought, I have still come out inconclusive (it has been a while since I did analysis). Per your instruction, the summand becomes $\frac{z}{(z-n)n}$. Taking the modulus, we have $|\frac{z}{n(z-n)}|\leq |\frac{N}{n(n-N)}|$. However, it is not apparent how I can transform the denominator into a power of $n^2$ without dragging in an $-Nn$ term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the argument from above comments note that it is enough to consider $n>2N$ since first few terms do not affect convergence. For $n >2N$ we have $\frac N {n(n-N)} <\frac N {n^{2}/2}=\frac {2N} {n^{2}}$.